# Comparing two files using awk and printing contains which are matching from other files

Tags: linux, awk

I have two files:

file1.txt

```
919167,hutch,mumbai
919594,idea,mumbai
```

file2.txt

```
919167000000
919594000000
```

Output

```
919167000000,hutch,mumbai
919594000000,idea,mumbai
```

How can I achieve this using AWK? I've got a huge file of phone numbers which needs to be compared like this. I believe Awk can handle it; if not please let me know how can I do this.

---

#### Extra definitions

- *Is the common part always a 6-digit number?* Yes always 6.
- *Are the two files already sorted?* file1 is not sorted. file2 can be sorted.
- *Are the trailing digits in file 2 always zeros?* No, these are phone numbers this can vary, purpose of this is to get series information of the phone number.
- *Is there any danger of file 1 containing three records for a given number while file 2 contains 2 records, or is it one-to-one?* It's one-to-one.
  Can there be records in file 1 with no match in file 2, or vice versa?_ Yes.
- *If so, do you want to see the unmatched records?* Yes I want both records.

---

#### Extended data

file1.txt

```
919167,hutch,mumbai
919594,idea,mumbai
918888,airtel,karnataka
```

file2.txt

```
919167838888
919594998484
919212334323
```

Output Expected:

```
919167838888,hutch,mumbai
919594998484,idea,mumbai
919212334323,nomatch,nomatch
```

Comment: Is the common part always a 6-digit number?  Are the two files already sorted?  The data shown is sorted.  Are the trailing digits in file 2 always zeros?  Is there any danger of file 1 containing three records for a given number while file 2 contains 2 records, or is it one-to-one?  Can there be records in file 1 with no match in file 2, or vice versa?  If so, do you want to see the unmatched records?

Comment: @user1719039: Please see the changes I've made.

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in a comment, there's a lot of unstated information needed to give a definitive answer.  However, we can make some plausible guesses:

1. The common number is the first 6 digits of file 2 (we don't care about the trailing digits, but will simply copy them to the output).
2. The files are sorted in order.
3. If there are unmatched records in either file, those records will be ignored.

The tools of choice are probably `sed` and `join`:

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]\{6\}\)/\1,\1/' file2.txt |
join -t, -o 1.2,2.2,2.3 - file1.txt
```

This edits `file2.txt` to create a comma-separated first field with the 6-digit phone number followed by all the rest of the line.  The input is fed to the `join` command, which joins on the first column, and outputs the 'rest of the line' (column 2) from `file2.txt` and columns 2 and 3 from `file1.txt`.

If the phone numbers are variable length, then the matching operation is horribly complex.  For that, I'd drop into Perl (or Python) to do the work.  If the data is unsorted, it can be sorted before being fed into the commands.  If you want unmatched records, you can specify how to handle those in the options to `join`.

---

The extra information needed is now available.  The key information is the 6-digits is fixed — phew!  Since you're on Linux, I'm assuming `bash` is available with 'process substitution':

```
sort file2.txt |
sed 's/^\([0-9]\{6\}\)/\1,\1/' |
join -t, -o 1.2,2.2,2.3 -a 1 -a 2 -e 'no-match' - <(sort file1.txt)
```

If process substitution is not available, simply sort `file1.txt` in situ:

```
sort -o file1.txt file1.txt
```

Then use `file1.txt` in place of `<(sort file1.txt)`.

---

I think the comment might be asking for inputs such as:

#### file1.txt

```
919167,hutch,mumbai
919594,idea,mumbai
902130,airtel,karnataka
```

#### file2.txt

```
919167000000
919594000000
919342313242
```

#### Output

```
no-match,airtel,karnataka
919167000000,hutch,mumbai
919342313242,no-match,no-match
919594000000,idea,mumbai
```

If that's not what the comment is about, please clarify by editing the question to add the extra data and output in a more readable format than comments allow.

---

Working with the extended data, this mildly modified command:

```
sort file2.txt |
sed 's/^\([0-9]\{6\}\)/\1,\1/' |
join -t, -o 1.2,2.2,2.3 -a 1 -e 'no-match' - <(sort file1.txt)
```

produces the output:

```
919167838888,hutch,mumbai
919212334323,no-match,no-match
919594998484,idea,mumbai
```

which looks rather like a sorted version of the desired output.  The `-a n` options control whether the unmatched records from file 1 or file 2 (or both) are printed; the `-e` option controls the value printed for the unmatched fields.  All of this is readily available from the man pages for `join`, of course.

Comment: i think it works but one change though,pradeep@pradeep-Vostro-1014:~$ sort file2.txt | sed 's/^\([0-9]\{6\}\)/\1,\1/' | join -t, -o 1.2,2.2,2.3 -a 1 -a 2 -e 'no-match' - file1.txt
919167838888,hutch,mumbai
919594998484,idea,mumbai
no-match,airtel,karnataka-----> for this desired output should be 919342313242,no-match,no-match. is this possible?

Comment: I can't work out where the 919342313242 number comes from, or exactly what the data files look like.  Please edit the question (where you can format the information sensibly) to include the extra data lines in the input files, and the desired output.

Comment: thnks . the above command with Join is working fyn. Will i be able to run on Huge data of phone numbers ..like millions of numbers :).

Comment: Yes; I would expect it to work fine.  If there's a problem with large quantities of data, it will be in the sort operations, not the `join`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file2.txt file1.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}

FNR==NR {
    sub(/[ \t]+$/, "")
    line = substr($0, 0, 6)
    array[line]=$0
    next
}

{
    printf ($1 in array) ? $0"\n" : "FILE1 no match --> "$0"\n"
    dup[$1]++
}

END {
    for (i in array) {
        if (!(i in dup)) {
            printf "FILE2 no match --> %s\n", array[i]
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } FNR==NR { sub(/[ \t]+$/, ""); line = substr($0, 0, 6); array[line]=$0; next } { printf ($1 in array) ? $0"\n" : "FILE1 no match --> "$0"\n"; dup[$1]++} END { for (i in array) if (!(i in dup)) printf "FILE2 no match --> %s\n", array[i] }' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Comment: I will add support for what doesn't match within the next 6-12 hours

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2","$3;next}{for(i in a){if($1~/i/) print $1","a[i]}}' your_file
```

Comment: Hi sarathi , i got two files as input.

Comment: @Jonathan, thnk you. I had used combination of sed & join as per your above comment, it worked fine for me. I'm kinda happy to avoid DB access for such things now. Thank you all. Lot of things to learn yet..looking forward for more.